# Have a general query about VOIP for a webapp, would like someone to point me in right direction

Tags: web-applications, webrtc, sip, voip

I'd like to find out the best way to go about building a voip webapp (just for voice and text). We want to create a service that uses voip. The customer would log onto our site and connect to our freelancers. I'd like it all to run through our web app and not need any downloads for users or freelancers.

Would it be better to try integrate something like riot.im or mumble(if possible) or use a service like sip2sip or webrtc? We are trying to test our service to see if it will work so want to use something cheap or free but also want something that will be able handle a lot of traffic if it grows(so scalable).

Important to mention there would be multiple voice chats running simultaneously

Hope that all makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't go with a SIP backend if you aren't planning to connect calls to regular phone numbers as well.

Also important is to see if you need recording or group calls, as these would require backend media servers to be added.

There's a large number of alternatives for developers to go by, so it is hard to answer. riot.im is based on matrix.org, which you can use for this purpose. You will need WebRTC in any way to get voice in the web browser with no installation or download.

Check out this landscape map for potential vendors and projects to start from: https://bloggeek.me/webrtc-developer-tools-landscape/

Comment: Ok thanks. If it is just browser based could i leave the sip side/matrix.org all together and build the whole thing out of webrtc? No recording or group chats in the beginning maybe later. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure you can, but you'll still need to come up with some kind of signaling and it should be a solid one.